# Is there a way to customize the Options dialog in QGIS 2.14.6?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.14, context-menu

I'm creating a deployment package to update QGIS from V2.8 (wien) to V2.14 (essen (LTR)).

In QGIS 2.14 there is a new "Advanced" section under "Settings > Options", see screenshot:

[image]

Can this menu item be removed from the Options menu?  I don't want to completely disable the "Options" menu as it is used, however I don't want the users access this advanced set of options.