# Removal of Advanced Tab in Settings

Tags: qgis

We are on the verge of rolling out 'Essen' 2.14.

Our IT people are reluctant to roll out QGis with the ‘Advanced’ tab being available in ‘Settings’ > ‘Options’ > ‘Advanced’

Does anyone know of a way to remove it?

Comment: A _very_ similar question was asked only several days ago: [Is there a way to customize the Options dialog in QGIS 2.14.6?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209197/is-there-a-way-to-customize-the-options-dialog-in-qgis-2-14-6)

Comment: You could hide the entire `Settings` menu by going to `Settings > Customization > Menus > mSettingsMenu > mActionsOptions` and uncheck it. When you restart QGIS, the `Settings` menu will not be available.

Comment: Thank-you for that - we might try it.  It does seem detrimental however to remove the options altogether - main reason being able to alter snapping options is very useful.

Comment: You can still access the snapping options from `Settings > Snapping options...` :)